# Is there a tool similar to FlashDevelop for Ubuntu?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ubuntu

For developing Flash / ActionScript packages on Windows, there is no better free tool than [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org).

Unfortunately, its reliance on the .Net framework make it ill-suited for AS3 development on Ubuntu. (My attempts to get it working with Mono failed - the installer wouldn't even work.)

Is there a similar tool for use with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there any other free decent IDE's.

You could try FDT - a plugin for  eclipse, although it is not free. There is an install guide here: http://varga-multimedia.com/2010/02/07/how-to-install-fdt-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @George, you would be pretty popular if you did :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Minibuilder. Not yet as complex as FlashDevelop but it's a good start and being an air application it runs under Linux.
http://code.google.com/p/minibuilder/

Make sure you install the latest version, currently (1.1.3) to bypass the "Keyboard not working issue"

See the link at the end of this page:
http://code.google.com/p/minibuilder/issues/detail?id=21

Also on youtube there is a proof of concept of FD running under Linux. FD4 may have better integration with Linux under Wine

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d542anpD-Lg
http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7535

Answer (score 0):

According to this Thread you could use WINE
http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=8360

I'll give it  a try later and give some feedback in this post.